# How to batch convert .mkv to .mp4 using ffmpeg in macOS?

Tags: macos, ffmpeg, video-conversion

I am using this command to convert from `.mkv` to `.mp4` in macOS:

```
> ffmpeg -i input/*.mkv -codec copy mp4/%~n.mp4
zsh: no matches found: input/*.mkv
> ffmpeg -i "input/*.mkv" -codec copy mp4/%~n.mp4
ffmpeg version 6.0 Copyright (c) 2000-2023 the FFmpeg developers
  built with Apple clang version 14.0.3 (clang-1403.0.22.14.1)
  configuration: --prefix=/opt/homebrew/Cellar/ffmpeg/6.0 --enable-shared --enable-pthreads --enable-version3 --cc=clang --host-cflags= --host-ldflags= --enable-ffplay --enable-gnutls --enable-gpl --enable-libaom --enable-libaribb24 --enable-libbluray --enable-libdav1d --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopus --enable-librav1e --enable-librist --enable-librubberband --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsrt --enable-libsvtav1 --enable-libtesseract --enable-libtheora --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvmaf --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libxvid --enable-lzma --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-frei0r --enable-libass --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libspeex --enable-libsoxr --enable-libzmq --enable-libzimg --disable-libjack --disable-indev=jack --enable-videotoolbox --enable-neon
  libavutil      58.  2.100 / 58.  2.100
  libavcodec     60.  3.100 / 60.  3.100
  libavformat    60.  3.100 / 60.  3.100
  libavdevice    60.  1.100 / 60.  1.100
  libavfilter     9.  3.100 /  9.  3.100
  libswscale      7.  1.100 /  7.  1.100
  libswresample   4. 10.100 /  4. 10.100
  libpostproc    57.  1.100 / 57.  1.100
input/*.mkv: No such file or directory
```

Is it possible to convert `.mkv` to `.mp4` batch in macOS 13.2?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a simple `for` loop like this:

```bash
for file in *.mkv; do ffmpeg -i "$file" -c copy "mp4/${file%.*}.mp4"; done
```

It basically executes the command for each `.mkv`, deletes the extension with parameter expansion (`${file%.*}`) and adds `.mp4` instead.

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I got to work for me since the first answer didn't work for me. I'm on macOS Sonoma.

```bash
for f in *.mkv; do ffmpeg -i "$f" -c copy "${f%.mkv}.mp4"; done
```

I give credit to [this post.](https://gist.github.com/jamesmacwhite/58aebfe4a82bb8d645a797a1ba975132)

Keep in mind that when you do this container swap. The resulting MP4 file might not play nice with macOS. For example: Quicktime will not play audio only video. Thumbnail might not be there.

I found a solution for this by adding the the `-tag:v hvc1` parameter in your FFmpeg command make your HEVC file work on Apple devices.

Example:

```bash
ffmpeg -i Aliens1996.mkv -c copy -tag:v hvc1 Aliens1996.mp4
```

*But* I have not figured out how to batch convert with this tag because I think some of my MKV's are already HEVC?